# How to fix a zoom lens that is sticky at a particular focal length?

Tags: lens, canon, zoom, repair

I have the Canon 18-55mm lens. When I zoom out from 55mm to 18mm, the lens works fine until 22mm, where it seems to be stuck and you must then use a bit more force. I saw in many sites that this is common for the 18-55 lens. Has anyone had the same problem, and can it be avoided or resolved in any way?

Comment: Is 22mm the point at which the lens reaches the closest to the camera and starts moving back out again?  This is a complete guess, but I'd hazard it is a problem with the lens elements used for macro zooming and is likely something that can't be fixed without taking the lens apart.

Comment: I can reach 18. It's something like... from 22 to 18 I need more strenght, if do it on the same movement it stops. (Sorry for my english) and thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I verified this on my own version of that lens from my old xTi.  That's normal behavior.  The lens goes between macro and standard zoom.  If you notice, when you put the lens at 55 it is a long way out, then as you move to 24, it slowly pulls back up against the body of the lens.  Then from 24 to 18, it pushes back out again.  Thing is, it does this a) over a much shorter distance and b) with a different set of lens elements to shift to the macro side of the lens.

You are moving more material further with less rotation, so it is harder to move.  Don't worry about it unless it gets hard enough that you feel like you are going to do damage.

Comment: Thanks a lot AJ, with this explanation I can understand why is happening, and also I don't pay a lot of money for a repair that is nothing at all. One just little thing if I don't bother you: I can assume this happens with all lens of the same focal length or on the good ones (like gold or red line) this is not so notorious ? Thanks a lot! :) +1 and mark as answer!

Comment: @Leandro - not all lenses use the same kind of mechanism.  My 17-40mm L series (the red line you speak of) for example is a wide angle lens and thus doesn't have that kind of movement.  It's specifically because the kit 18-55 shifts between standard zoom and wide-angle macro.  Only lenses that exhibit this behavior would have the characteristic back and forth movement.  It would be recognizable on any lens that has it though as you would have a similar back and forth movement on all of them that operate that way.